# Favoriting a tweet that is in the favorites of someone you don't follow

Tags: twitter, twitter-favorites

If I favorited a tweet on a person's favourites that I do not follow, will they get a notification of it?

I'm on person X's profile and I look at their favourites but I don't follow them. I favourite a video that isn't their video, just a video they favourited. Does person X get a notification I favourited the same video? Because then that would be weird since I don't follow them.

Comment: There are tweets favorited / liked by over a million users. How would it work if everyone was notified of other users favoriting the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, X will not get notification, but the original poster of that video will get a notification that you liked (favourite) his/her video. And it doesn't matter you follow them or not.